# Custom columns for entity after load

Tags: php, symfony

I have an entity,

```
// src/Acme/StoreBundle/Entity/Product.php
namespace Acme\StoreBundle\Entity;

class Product
{
    protected $name;
    protected $price;
    protected $description;
}
```

I when I get a product record I want to join the name and description.  Something like,

```
// src/Acme/StoreBundle/Entity/Product.php
namespace Acme\StoreBundle\Entity;

class Product
{
    protected $name;
    protected $price;
    protected $description;
    protected $heading;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->heading = $this->name . ' ' . $this->description;
    }
}
```

I've tried setting heading on the preLoad event, in the constructor.  After its creation and before serialising.  Nothing seems to work.   How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use just getter:

```
public function getHeading()
{
    return $this->name . ' ' . $this->description;
}
```

Comment: Tried this also.  Looks like its actually a problem with the JMS serialiser removing the properties.